# Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use?

Tags: support, faq, mobile-web, mobile-app

I like using Stack Overflow (or any other Stack Exchange sites) and was wondering if there was an app I could install on my phone or other device that would allow me to use the site on-the-go or straight from my desktop.

Some systems to consider:

- Windows 8
- Android
- iPhone/iOS

What are some apps that I could install to my computer or phone to enhance my Stack Exchange experience?

[Return to FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931)

Answer (score 45):

If you didn't know, every Stack Exchange site has a *responsive layout* - meaning that if you access the desktop site on a mobile device, it will render in a mobile-optimized format. Most views, including the homepage, questions, and search render in this view, though some pages may have been ported over not yet.

We **used** to offer official mobile apps, but those are no longer available for any platform. These apps [are no longer supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app) and the [supporting infrastructure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/updated-mobile-app-infrastructure-has-been-decommissioned) has been taken down, so existing installations no longer work.

If you strongly prefer a native app over using the website, some third-party developers have written some apps that you may be able to use to view the site; however, due to API limitations, not all features may be supported:

- [View iOS apps at Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/iphone+app)
- [View Android apps at Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android+app)

Still looking? Try browsing [all the apps available at Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app).

Comment: If you hit the mobile option, and then use previous page to get out of it, when you click on a question, it goes back to mobile view.  You need to click "full site" to go back to default behavior.

Comment: Since [all of the mobile apps are no longer supported/developed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342028/335251), this answer probably needs to be updated accordingly.

Comment: @V2Blast There is already a note in the answer that they are no longer developed. What needs updating?

Comment: @animuson: Whoops, I didn't notice that - I was looking by the the app links themselves.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT Do you know if this was asked about on Meta anywhere? It was not intentional for that to disappear, so if there's a question about why it disappeared it'd be nice to get a status-review on that so we can look into it more. Rather not have that just slip into the cracks with a hidden edit.

Comment: @animuson it hasn't been asked yet, though [some recent meta posts about SO app on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400334) linked to other meta posts ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373307), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075)) with comments about SE Android app being gone. Should I post a question about it for you to tag it with status-review?

Comment: @MetaAndrewT That'd be good. The Stack Overflow app was a separate app. That one *should* be gone from the stores. The Stack Exchange app is not maintained but was supposed to still stick around.

Comment: @animuson [done!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353133)

Comment: ", it will render in a mobile-optimized format. " As if! The buttons and links are still way too small to click on I'm a mobile device s well as the text input for editing answers being too small to scroll through, one has to manually zoom in to click anything which kind of defeats the point