# Why don't someone create a good android app for stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request, android

I have been going through this for sometime. I badly need a good android app for 'StackOverflow' or for all the 'StackExchange' communities. Any possibilities?

Comment: What is wrong with using your favorite browser?

Comment: The API only supports [writing of comments](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write). So, as for writing, that's all a 3rd party app could support. Still then: success! ;-)

Comment: I posted this question just out of curiosity. You could have just provided with the answers. Downvoting huh... Thanks anyway.

Comment: and pointing out, none of those android apps have good reviews in play store.

Comment: Can we make my own stackoverflow android app using its API? stackoverflow will provide the API to get the list of questions answers?

Answer (score 0):

By app, what do you mean? Well, as animuson pointed out , you need to see this question - [Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use) .

Best bet is [Stack-anywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rectangularsoftware.stackanywhere)

here's the pic!

[image]