# Official Stack Overflow mobile app

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web

This question has been [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use) before in 2010, but I am sure many of us would like to see an official app to use Stack Overflow, which allows interaction (votes, reviews, etc) instead of just reading questions.

Are there any plans to build an official app, or is the intent to use the mobile versions of the sites?

Comment: Though, if it properly rendered on all devices, an HTML5 version of SO would be just as effective.

Comment: I just wish the mobile version of the chat had the same reply, quote, and star features. Unfortunately the non-mobile version attaches the chatbox to the middle of the scrollable view. So I can reply, etc. but I have to put up with much scrolling.

Comment: If this feature-request gets over 50 upvotes, I'd consider developing an iOS app at least, that could support those features (either via disassembling the HTML, or by the 'official' API).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The API currently only supports reading for most types of posts (except comments).  See [Stack Exchange API v2.0](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) for a list of methods.  (Note the ones that are tagged [auth required].)

Comment: @BilltheLizard that doesn't mean you can't scrape web pages for the proper POST paths and such, or simply have an authorized web browser in the background.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII But it does mean that you can't use the official API for those functions.  Just FYI.