# Is there any official Stack Overflow Android app?

Tags: support, stackapps, android

Is there any official Stack Overflow Android app?

Other than the Stack Overflow apps in Google Play which are nothing more than web browser type apps?

Why is the official Stack Overflow for Android app still not developed?

There is a real need for this app, since its not very user friendly to login from a browser on pc/tab/phone to view the questions & answers.

More importantly to get real time notification and increase portability.!!

Comment: As of writing this comment, there is an official Android app, and plans to develop an iOS app. Also see [Do Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites have an app I can use?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use)

Comment: Now yes, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.stackoverflow

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any official Stack Overflow Android app?

Not one currently publicly available, but you can view what's available over on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com).

For read-only access, there's nothing preventing the community-built apps from providing the same level of functionality as the full site, but I don't know to what extent any of the available ones do.

> Why is the official Stack Overflow for Android app still not developed?

Now that they've [hired someone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/229741/kasra-rahjerdi) specifically for this job, the application is currently undergoing [pre-release testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app?rq=1), and will be available sometime in the not-so-distant future. You can help test the application by following the instructions in that announcement.

Comment: Nice find in the Careers! So it means they do plan to expand into the mobile market?

Comment: Seemingly so, yes, though I don't personally know what that entails.

Comment: Any top developer/ with highest reputation on Stack overflow would like to make this app for free!! Since this site has helped all of them any one would like to contribute by doing it!! ""????""

Comment: I was going the mention the same thing as  @Metalhead1247.It could be possible to make a team of great developers from StackOverflow itself and develop a great app for StackOverflow.

Comment: If anyone still looking for the app, there's one [here at play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin)

Comment: Great idea to create a mobile app for stack overflow.