# Help us test the alpha version of our Android app

Tags: support, android-app

We are in the early stages of development of the official Stack Exchange Android app and we need your help with testing. To set a few expectations: there will be bugs, crashes, and missing features, all of which will be fixed in [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/146719).

We are initially targeting Android devices running [Jelly Bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.1_Jelly_Bean_.28API_level_16.29) (Android 4.1 or higher) starting with phones (up to ~5 inch) and eventually moving our way to tablets.

To register for alpha testing [sign up here](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/1DW1zNni6WHbOc1lorFK-lFvP3RSeCUaQAf-OVaAyHso/viewform).

After you register we will send you an invite to a private Google community where you can find a link to download our app directly from the [Google Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play) store. **The invitations will be sent out in waves, so if you don’t get an invite immediately, be patient.**

Crash reports will be automatically reported back to us using [Crittercism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crittercism). Bugs or feature requests should be reported here on meta and tagged [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app). Please do not use the Google community to report bugs.

As always, we welcome your feedback and are committed to building the best mobile app possible for browsing the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Queue the people waiting for official iOS versions... like me! ;)

Comment: Minor gripe, but on the sign up form it says "Please provide us a link to one of your user profiles on Stack Exchange"... Should everyone theoretically have ONLY one profile...?

Comment: @TronicZomB At least the grammar allows for the possibility that you have more than one. ;)

Comment: Should we avoid reporting bugs on tablets for now, or should we already test the app on a tablet if we have one?

Comment: Android.SE mod here, you may want to cross post to our meta site too! http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TronicZomB You can have profiles on each of the various Stack Exchange sites. For example, [you have 19](http://stackexchange.com/users/2363364/troniczomb?tab=accounts).

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Ahh good point! I was reading it with a different interpretation in my head. :)

Comment: @MadScientist yes, please refrain from bug reports on a tablet. We are just testing the phone version for now.

Comment: @DavidFullerton Understood. Though I hope you'll be targeting tablets soon, and I assume you're using fragments already and the tablet version won't be too difficult to implement.

Comment: Cyanogenmod is your friend, @animuson.

Comment: @Shog9: Are you crazy? You know how long it took me to figure out how to install it the first time? I'm not an Android super-nerd like some people. :P

Comment: Well... I guess you don't *have* to build it from source if you don't want to, @ani. BTW: [android.se]

Comment: Damn. My phone still has 2.3.7 and is unlikely to get an update any time soon or indeed ever.

Comment: I'm still on Froyo. And Cyanogen is only supported till Gingerbread on my phone. >.<

Comment: Best luck for the cool apps and thanks for the new initiative (mobile app)!! I will be sure helping for resolving bugs if any and will provide feedback/reviews if any.

Comment: Just for clarification: "private Google community" = G+ circle? I'm avoiding all those "special social features" (not wanting my data spread more than they are already), and several others as well. Why not sending the invite by mail? There's a mail address registered with SE for each user, and mods/admins IMHO can access it. Being an official SE app, this should be a possible way :)

Comment: @Izzy that is a feature of the Google Android developer tools that allows the developer to distribute a beta version to a specific set of users via the Play store. And that feature uses Google+ to create the access list.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks for clarification -- I was afraid of that. Well, looks like I'll have to wait for the release then (or at least an "open beta").

Comment: @Izzy [Looks like it is either a Google Group or a Google+ community that is required for that feature](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks again! Google Groups might work :)

Comment: I accidentally filled out the form and clicked the submit button just as I saw the "4.1+" requirement. I have Android 4.0.4. Are you sure you don't want anyone testing the device on slightly older versions? As long as you aren't using any special APIs introduced in 4.1 and haven't explicitly set 4.1 in `minSdkVersion`, I would still be willing to test.

Comment: @NathanOsman you're welcome to try it - don't expect it to work as well is it could using 4.1+

Comment: Am curious if it will be open source?

Comment: We haven't decided @Tshepang - currently it is not.

Comment: Please, do make an app for Windows Phone 8...

Comment: @J.Steen I'm working on a pretty nice SE iOS client. Stay tuned - beta testing soon!

Comment: I signed up about 3 days ago, and I still haven't gotten the invitation. Is there something wrong, or are the invitations sent out scarcely?

Comment: We're still doing some last minute polishing after letting in a few staff.  We uncovered some issues that would be bad for you to encounter @CodyGuldner - stay tuned, we haven't forgotten about you.

Comment: @CodyGuldner Aside from what Geoff said, see the question: "The invitations will be sent out in waves, so if you don’t get an invite immediately, be patient." -- we won't invite everyone at once, so it may be a while either way (see point 11 on http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/BetaTest.html for the main reason).

Comment: @balpha, GeoffDalgas thanks for the feedback, I'm looking forward to try it out!

Comment: Will the Nexus 7 users get to test with the phone users? For instance, since I'm running ParanoidAndroid, my tablet is in phone mode.

Comment: What breaking edge new feature(s) are you guys using that you have to start at 4.1. :( Still running 2.3.

Comment: Well...I'm going to be a _fun_ beta tester.  I'll be providing tons of feedback and bugs for you guys.  Question:  I've actually put out a few bugs already.  Would you prefer if I trickled them (and my impressions) out slowly, or would you prefer a monolithic, "THIS IS BORKED FIX PLZ" type of post?  I can do either-or.

Comment: @Makato How about both?

Comment: Looks like it's out of private beta: [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.b5d.android&hl=en)

Comment: @DannyBeckett this is not the official Stack Exchange android app. Stack Remote just happens to use our logo (which we will try and rectify).

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Aww shiz! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Geoff: Especially as [some reviewers think you're endorsing it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.b5d.android&reviewId=Z3A6QU9xcFRPRTZrU1phRFBWZDZ0d1FnYWN2T0s3eEYxZXliN1RLRkk3aDZyeFZidVY2aG54cTZBS3lNNjVRVHpLamJ6bFlveG9NVml1bmJvN3ZvMTZjbTRj&hl=en).

Comment: So Gingerbreads can't participate?

Comment: How long is the alpha period?

Comment: I've been waiting for a while now as well. It would be nice to know when the next wave of invites will be sent but, like they said, be patient. After reading the link @balpha posted, point 11 does make sense.

Comment: We have just sent out another batch of invitations.  If you haven't received yours it's still on the way.  We are bringing in people slowly so we don't receive a lot of the same bug reports.

Comment: It seems [109 questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app) are tagged with [meta-tag:android-app] and I can see many issues/bugs are already fixed in current version but then those questions must be tagged with [meta-tag:status-completed] tag.

Comment: Can this app be downloaded and installed directly to the phone, or it can be installed only throught the Google Store?

Comment: We are using the alpha release system available in the play store. This release method requires a Google account that matches an account that you have on our network.  For this reason we won't be releasing via a direct download.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas a bit stupid if I have registered my account here with yahoo and later started using android and you keep me stuck forever without app or you force me to lose all reputation here and start from square no1 with gmail account.. bad move.. or there is some solution I missed..

Comment: @Ewoks - If I am not mistaken, you can always also attach a Google account to your Stack Exchange account. This will ensure that you can login using either.

Comment: thanks for that.. I found option and it works ;)

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Your most recent comment reveals upon mouseover that it was posted from the app. What is the point of this "feature"?

Comment: It's more than a month but still waiting to get the link of the alpha version.

Comment: There should be a designated chat room for app users to discuss things (confirm bugs, gauge suggestions, explain small things etc.)

Comment: @juergend invitations are still rolling out.  We are on a slow release cycles as not to overwhelm our testers.  Be patient - yours is coming.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I've tried to sign up twice this year (months apart) but received no invite. Is the process intelligent enough to realise that `foo@bar.com` might be a valid Google account email address or do I actually need one that ends in `@gmail.com`?

Comment: I'm pleased to report that the app works extremely well on my new Nexus 5.

Comment: This would definitely be something I'd volunteer for if it supported Gingerbread devices.. :(

Comment: I hope you don't disqualify users that have flashed their device with a custom ROM. My Motorola Defy doesn't have an official Jelly Bean ROM, but I flashed it with CyanogenMod, so I have Android 4.1. Please don't disqualify me.

Comment: We don't disqualify anyone.  If you want to try it then add your name to the list and we'll get you an invite.

Comment: Any ETA for tablet users?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas are invites still rolling out?

Comment: Yep, they sure are.  We're getting close to the end of our list.

Comment: Why this app dont have support for phone having android version 2.3.3 gingerbread, I am using it and wanna participate in this app testing!

Comment: @Geoff I've been waiting 2+ months... where are the invitations sent out? Email?

Comment: @Geoff Still waiting... why is it taking so long?

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow you were mailed an invite on 12/23 - I'll resend.

Comment: @Geoff Okay, thank you. Was the email address `odxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com`? (where `x` is some other character)

Comment: @Geoff if the latest wave of emails was sent on 12/23, and I just signed up, will I be waiting long for an invitation?

Comment: @Trojan no - I'll be acting on these a lot faster.

Comment: **Congratulations StackExchange for releasing Android app** successfully. But still I am not sure whether StackExchange Android developers has resolved all the issues/suggestion/bugs tagged with <kbd>android-app</kbd>, if not then you should otherwise it seems like testers work and time is in vain.

Comment: I agree with you @Paresh - we are not done here.  We are going to keep making improvements and address as many issues as we can.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Superb! and that's indeed required to make this app more polished and bug free. Thanks

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I was worried just because some issues aren't resolved yet but must be, for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215232/issue-in-site-selection-drop-down

Comment: Note: From [Tthe tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app): *"Note: the app is no longer supported since May 2020"*