# Unable to follow links in comments on Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks, android-app

I haven't been able to crash the [Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app) (yet). But, I'm unable to follow links that are apart of the comments. When I attempt to click on the link, I just get the context menu to vote up the comment.

I have a Nexus 4 running 4.3, if it matters.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Repro on Galaxy S4 running 4.2.2

Comment: and if those links point to an internal question/answer, please display it in the app instead of opening a browser window.

Comment: Yep, we discussed this and have a plan... stay tuned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Version 0.1.2 should allow comments to open links to our network of sites or any links in a browser.

Because of a bug this doesn't work with all links, and also interferes with the comment popup menu. It should work correctly in version 0.1.3.

Comment: Wonderful news to hear! Good job on the development! Full steam ahead!

Comment: I had an update to version 0.1.1 when I woke up this morning but this wasn't resolved. Is it coming in a later release?

Comment: Thanks @balpha for the clarification

Comment: Indeed it's fixed in v0.1.2

Comment: I was about to say the bug made its way back in, but after trying a few more times it seems the problem is my fat fingers on something smaller than a galaxy note... may be time for a closer look at [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196806/25163)?