# No pinch zoom for text

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I'm using the alpha version of the android app on the first generation nexus 7 tablet.

The font size is a little bit small for my liking and I'm not able to pinch zoom to increase the font size.

Is this a feature that is planned in the release?

Comment: Not speaking for the dev's here, but be careful with the tablet thing and the app. From the [opening post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app) "We are initially targeting [...] phones (up to ~5 inch) and eventually moving our way to tablets." On my phone, I'd say the text is large enough because of the limited screen real estate. But I'll say a "change text size" option maybe cool to have?

Comment: @StevenV - On my tablet it's fine, but on my Galaxy Nexus I could stand a slightly larger text option. While I would prefer the suggestion above (pinch zoom), I'd be ok with some sort of size selection too (like on the Kindle and Bible apps).

Comment: I did read the post and know that tablets would be targeted later. This isn't a must have feature but like you said an option to increase the text size wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I Can read it on my phone but it's really small. I would actually prefer a font size setting over pinch/zoom

Answer (score 1):

[Font size on Android SE app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243170/font-size-on-android-se-app) has been marked as a duplicate of this, so I'll reopen discussion here.

Easy control of font size within the app should be a high on the wish list for developers.  First, it constitutes an accessibility issue, and second, a usability issue.

I am fully aware that I can change my system fonts, and that this would resolve the issue with this app.  That said, After years of fairly rigorous Android use, I haven't ever had to do that with any app I've ever used, and suggest there's a reason for that.

Comment: I have font size set to Huge on my ZTE Valet, but still the text size on this app is tiny.  The menus are fine, but the answers and comments are still barely readable.

Comment: @pak -- This is now fixed, changing system settings now changes all text sizes in the app.