# Increasing system text size only makes comment text bigger

Tags: bug, android-app

In the android app, I'd love for pinch-zoom text to be supported, but that's a [low-priority feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196806/no-pinch-zoom-for-text). Rather than gripe about that, I just went to increase the system text size. Alas, this only makes the *comment* text easier to read, not the question or answer text.

Running ICS 4.0.4 on a Samsung Galaxy tab 7.

#### Screen captures

With all system text set to normal size, the app looks like this:

[image]

After setting system text to large, the comment text gets bigger but not the question or answer text:

[image]

Comment: Why the downvotes? Are others unable to reproduce?

Comment: I added some screen captures for clarity. If this still gets mysterious downvotes, I may have to resort to hand-drawn circles and arrows. :D