# Re-sizable fonts (Zoom) for the Android App and confusing contact link

Tags: feature-request, android-app

The Android app is a great application.  I see two problems with it.  The fonts are too small.  I have to use a magnifying glass to read the messages.  At present I use it almost solely for a notification to my activity, to get to a computer so that I can read the information.

This could be resolved by adding adjustable fonts to the interface (zoom).

Also, the contact link for communication with the developer for comments like this (feature request) isn't clear.  It goes to the generic site where you can access all the sites.  A new user might be confused and type his question or comment in a place that's not meant for the app and get a bad experience by being reprimanded and have his question/comment down voted.

With my experience on this site, even I weren't sure.  I sent email asking where to post my feature request.  I was told to post it here with the suggested tags that I'm adding.

Looking for the developers attention to this, as well as why the re-sizable fonts are not included.

---

**Clarification and suggestion on the confusing contact link:**

As pointed out by Andrew T the link can go directly to this part of “Ask Question” with the appropriate “android-app” tag selected.  I would like to expand this by suggesting the link to have a flag  that will trigger a message to alert the user of the special area, with a description that makes it clear that it's not strictly just for questions and answers, but feature request, suggestions, and comments.

I notice a number of negative comments in the Google Play comment section.  I'm inclined to believe the negative comments are from some users who don't understand Stack Exchange and may be afraid to ask because they may not know exactly where to put their comments and suggestions...which might not be specific content that can be put into a clear qualifying question.

Comment: For some reason I had just assumed we had added in adjustable font sizes already... that'll be in a future update soon.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Great! I believe I used a misnomer in saying resize fonts, I meant zoom (of which I updated the wording).  I'm sure you knew this was what I meant, and was in your reference.  Anyway, with the zoom feature, the app will be even more superb.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi about contact link, I wonder if it's possible to go directly into "Ask question" activity with MSE site already selected and [tag:android-app] tag already set?

Comment: @AndrewT. That would be a great start. I updated my "question" to include your suggestion.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196806/no-pinch-zoom-for-text