# Font size on Android SE app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, accessibility, font-size

Is there a way to change font size in the Android SE app?  I can't find it if there is one.

I consider this to be an accessibility issue.

Update-- now beta testing the new upadate, and this feature is still needed

Comment: The app respects the system-wide font settings. Tried those?

Comment: Frankly, I haven't.  I imagine there's a reason why just about every application that involves reading text on the platform gives you got size control outside the system setting. While I appreciate the path to get this done quickly, it's a factor that pushed me right back to the Web platform.  Not a big deal, but I thought  the decision makers would want such input