# Make accepted check more distinct from non-accepted check on own questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

I am viewing one of my own questions, which has an accepted answer, in the Android app.

The checkmark for the accepted answer could be more distinct from those in the non-accepted answers. The former is a green check in a white field, while the others are a white check in a field with the same shade of green. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

It was a bit confusing and I had to confirm on my PC which answer was the accepted one.

Could this distinction be more clear? Perhaps simply no checkmark for the non-accepted answers?

Comment: This screenshot better have some **serious** freehand circles...

Comment: @StephenTG: Uh, oh.  wait!  gimme a minute!

Comment: [sarcasm] I'd having a hard time looking at the app UI with that many notifications too.

Comment: @StephenTG:  How's that?

Comment: +1 for freehand circles

Comment: And for actually being a legitimate concern and all that nonsense

Comment: *Yikes.* Oh, but at least you’re the asker.

Comment: The oscillation is strong with this one.

Comment: From where can I download android app ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя: You need to ask to participate in the alpha. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 0.1.43 which came out earlier last week, here's what the accepted and "accept" buttons look like.

The top view is the owner of a question looking at an answer that hasn't been accepted yet, the bottom view is anyone looking at an answer which has been marked as accepted.

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Fantastically more beterer.