# Green Accept button is misleading

Tags: discussion, bug, android-app

When I first saw the Accepted icon at the left, I interpreted it as being Accepted. *So, I thought it was a bug.* When I checked the answer online, I saw it wasn't accepted yet. So I accepted one of the answers, and the Accepted icon changed to the one seen at the right.

Given that, I think the green color is misleading. The site has gray Upvote, Downvote, and Accept icons. The app follows this, except for the Accept icon (which is green).

**EDIT:** Oh, wait. Looks like a duplicate of: [Make accepted check more distinct from non-accepted check on own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191302/)… On the other hand, I think they have different concerns. He focuses not having a checked icon for unaccepted answers, while I focus on the color. *Please flag this as dupe, if you think it is.*

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's definitely a confusing UI...

Comment: On the other hand, it seems like a different concern.

Comment: The concern is the same. The question was a bit mutilated because of pandering to the freehand circles crowd.