# Is there a full changelog for the Android app?

Tags: discussion, android-app

Is there a full changelog somewhere for the changes made to the Android StackExchange app?

Comment: Well, there is the [fixed bugs list and completed feature requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app+status-completed). :)

Comment: Is there a post about this SE app? Seen it mentioned a good few times now, but can only see something on Play that looks independent, using the read-only API, not associated with SE itself. What the what?

Comment: @GrantThomas See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app

Comment: @AnnaLear Reading that now - just from what I see on Play I don't see anything that looks legit. Okay, need to sign up... doing. ...done! Joy! Thank you.

Comment: Since signing up, I still haven't received a linky... :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. We try to put the major changes into the Play Store's newest changes field when we upload a new version, and as Sha Wiz Dow Ard [says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191969/is-there-a-full-changelog-for-the-android-app#comment598114_191969), there's the list of the Meta questions. But beyond that, maintaining a detailed changelog (especially in these early stages where so much is in flux) just isn't worth the work.

If someone has a concrete question – "X works for me but not for my friend, was that fixed between 0.1.27 and 0.1.31?" –, feel free to ask (just drop into the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), I'm usually there for most of the UTC day). But a full version-by-version breakdown of all changes is too much hassle.