# Official StackExchange app says my question is not available?

Tags: bug, android-app

I recently posted a new question on Android Enthusiasts using the official StackExchange app for Android. Right after posting the question, the app said that my question is not available.

> The question is not available, it may have been deleted.

Deleted? Already?...

Then I navigated to my user name to see my recent activity. There it was! I could see the question I just posted. But if I tapped on the link to try to open it, the app kept complaining about my question not being available.

> The question is not available, it may have been deleted.

But 7 minutes after posting the question, I could see my question. Here are some screenshots that showcase this issue.

[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]
[image: screen3]

This is not the first time this happens. This appears to be more or less normal behavior of the app. I don't use the StackExchange app very often to post questions. But I had exactly the same message come up when I posted a question a few months ago (and some app version numbers earlier).

This is not a major issue, but you should try to address this nevertheless. It's a small bug, but addressing it might imply much bigger changes... which might explain why it's still present... I don't really know, I'm guessing. I just thought I would let you know about it, in case you are not aware of it.

*For the record, the phone is Galaxy S4 Plus (GT-I9506) running Android 4.4.2. Version number of the app is 1.0.50.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is due to [this answer from Kasra](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238271).

Comment: The wording in that error message is a bit different. But yeah, it looks like the same issue. The answer you linked to is dated Aug 19 this year. I have been seeing this issue long before that. As I suspected, it appears to be a deeply rooted problem, related to the database setup. Let's just hope it will be sorted out in the coming updates.

Comment: Issue is still present

Comment: I thought they had this sorted out already. I honestly haven't used the mobile app to post a question recently. I mostly use a computer for that, and the mobile app for getting notifications and posting comments. What version of the app are you using? I think I saw some mention about this in the app description a few updates back. But apparently, there is no [changelog for the mobile app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195666/how-about-a-changelog-for-the-android-app).