# Missing Moderator's diamond in the Android application

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Doesn't seem like the diamond is coming across in the application.  I know that Andrew Barber is a moderator, but  it doesn't seem to come across.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the report! That's definitely an oversight, we'll get it fixed soon.

Comment: Naw, I think it's just that nobody likes Andrew :)

Comment: SO has an android application..?

Comment: @aug [Help us test the Alpha version of our Android App](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show the moderator diamonds in version 0.1.4 and greater.