# There's no way to tell if a question has been closed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, android-app

The Android app doesn't appear to give any kind of indication that a question has been closed, which I feel leads to poor UX. As an illustrative example, consider [the (in)famous LOGO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo):

[image]

As you can see, the left screenshot is the main question page, and it contains no `[closed]` marker in the title. Not only that, but the "Add an answer" button is still available, and pressing it takes you to the text entry field as it normally does. It's only after you hit <kbd>Submit</kbd> or <kbd>Preview</kbd> that you're greeted with a message that says:

> This question has been closed or locked; no new answers will be accepted.

So, potentially, if I stumbled on to a closed question that I felt I could contribute to, I could end up spending time typing up an answer only to have it rejected at the very end.

Ideally, I think the question title should reflect that it's been closed and the "Add an answer" button should be disabled or hidden. In addition to this, it would seem logical that duplicates should have the link to the original, so that landing on a dupe via the Android app doesn't leave you at a dead end (this is not currently the case, either). Showing the specific close *reason* (and other post notices) would be great as well, but I could see that being of slightly less concern since I can always tap on the question title to view it in a browser if I'm really curious about the "why".

Comment: @Danny: Dude. [Help us test the Alpha version of our Android App](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200)

Comment: @AlEverett Nice, I missed that! (I deleted my last comment since it contained a link to an unofficial app that I thought was the one in beta).

Comment: Yep, this didn't make it into the alpha, but it should make it in soon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We now will only show the "Add an answer" button when a question has all of the signals we require to be answerable.  We also fixed the padding on that button.

Comment: This does seem to be addressed, *except* in the case where a question is closed and does not have any answers. In that situation I see "This question does not have any answers yet..." followed by the "Add an Answer" button, despite it being closed. Do you see that as well?

Comment: @eldarerathis: I'm still seeing it. Geoff: Really there should also be some "closed" indicator on the question's own tab, without having to swipe to the answers to notice that there's no "add an answer" button.

Comment: The new "Put on hold" banner at the bottom of the question looks good! I like that implementation.