# There's no way to tell if a question has been marked as duplicate in Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, android-app

Same as [There's no way to tell if a question has been closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192104/theres-no-way-to-tell-if-a-question-has-been-closed), there must be an indication saying that this question is marked as Duplicate otherwise android app user can't come to know about it. And that's the reason it doesn't contain <kbd>Add an answer</kbd> button.

Below is the snap of [Loading a question and doing a pull to refresh in the Android app on the question clears question details [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193031/loading-a-question-and-doing-a-pull-to-refresh-in-the-android-app-on-the-questio) which is marked by as duplicate.

[image]

There must be clear indication like this question is marked as duplicate by so and so moderators, I mean the same message as on site.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.24, thanks!

[image]