# Don't let me start answering closed questions!

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, android-app

> This is a bug report about the [implemented feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192104/theres-no-way-to-tell-if-a-question-has-been-closed)

This is [a closed question having no answers](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2450/189) with no indication on the question page.

[image]

Or on the answers page:

[image]

Or even when I start typing:

[image]

Version: 0.1.21

Comment: @FDinoff That feature-request has been implemented but it missed out on questions which do not have any answers. Hence, this is a **bug report** about that feature-request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed, it'll go out in the next app update, thanks!