# Why is there no official Stack Overflow Android app?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, android-app

I was looking at [google play](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=stackoverflow&hl=en) trying to find and official Stack Overflow app for an Android smartphone. Is there any reason why SO doesn't have any?

Comment: Yes there is a reason, and the reason is it is being developed.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app

Comment: hey guys I really dont get the -1 on this I think this is a valid question in fact when you google it you can't find this post because the "keywords" aren't strictly related to android and app, so how am I going to find it using google? to be honest try to be more polite to new users!

Comment: @Pedro I think it was a fair question. I agree users here can be fairly hostile - but it takes only a small number in such a huge community. I'm not sure what I can do about them but I *can* give you an upvote. :)

Comment: Related: *[Mobile app infrastructure has been decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/)* (2022-10-19).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We do have one. You've used a tag with dozens of questions about it. :)

It's currently in Alpha, and possibly not openly available for just anyone to download it on Google Play.

You can read about it and sign up for testing the alpha here:

**[Help us test the alpha version of our Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app)**

Comment: thanks! didn´t know about it