# Some users can still create bookmarks

Tags: bug, data-explorer, saves

The unfortunate decision has been made to evolve [Bookmarks into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves). One of the key changes was:

> Will my saved posts and lists be public?
>
> Nope!

and with that a whole bunch of Data Explorer queries got obsolete.

As the data migration was completed on October, 6th. I assumed the Votes table to be empty for votetypeid = 5 (Bookmark (former Favorite)). That is almost true. Some users managed to create [105 bookmarks after October, 12th](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1659838). I suspect those users might use a userscript, the API, the [(soon defunct) App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/mobile-app-infrastructure-being-decommissioned) or have found other means to postpone the inevitable.

In the small chance that there is a serious issue here that needs fixing, I report this bug and ask this to be investigated and possible patched. If this closes a loophole found by some users, I apologize upfront.

Comment: What kind of information did the SEDE queries gather or reveal? E.g., to get a list of URLs for one's own bookmarks? To aid in deleting bookmarks, but keep the references? Or something else?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum it can show which post(s) each user has bookmarked.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum basically per post which user bookmarked it. While you could via the site visit a userprofie to find their bookmarks, you couldn't the otherway around, aka: given a post, which users bookmarked it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9hya.png might potentially be via the app - which has a 'favourite' button for posts. I've favourited this post so we have a traceable datapoint

Comment: I can confirm - I'm still able to b̶o̶o̶k̶m̶a̶r̶k̶ favorite questions in the [official(ly deprecated) iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026/295232)

Comment: So .... with the migration they also ruined another feature for the App upfront. Oh well.