# What happened to FavoriteCount?

Tags: support, data-explorer, bookmarks, saves

On 10/22 I ran a query on the Data Science SEDE. In the Posts table I selected some columns, FavoriteCounts included. Looking at the results from the .csv I see a lot of different unique values for that column.
[image: a lot of unique values]
I ran a similar query today and now it's only Null or 0.
[image: no unique values]
Here are two matching rows. You can see I left out the ID column the first time I ran this, hence rerunning it today.
[image: comparing two rows]
Earlier today I had wondered if it had something to do with the migration from Bookmarks to Saves, but [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) says the migration was complete at the beginning of October.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [What does replacing of bookmarks with saves mean for SEDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383382)

Comment: Related: [Some users can still create bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383150/some-users-can-still-create-bookmarks)

Comment: Favorites and later Bookmarks were both public, anyone could see what any user has added to their Favorited or Bookmarks. However, Saves are private. That's a major and breaking change to the feature, but nothing we can do about it. It is not possible anymore to see what a user added to their Saves, and thus they also removed the counts from the public tables.

Comment: Thanks Shadow, that's what I wondered.

IMHO, it's unfortunate to loose the count. That's an anonymous bit of information that says something about the usefulness and interest generation of a question.

If anyone has ideas on other ways to get that info please share.