# Why is there no Stack app available for mobile devices?

Tags: discussion, android-app, meta, ios-app, mobile-web

### Description:

As every Stack user knows that Stack itself is a combination of many great platforms for different purposes. Its accessibility from a mobile device/remote device would impact its usability in a positive way.

### Question:

So, it's not that if the Stack team hasn't gotten over this topic, but the question still remains why isn't there an app for the Stack forum. Is it compatibility or a privacy issue or is there a funding problem?

Comment: I guess it is worth having a look at this announcement: [Updated: Mobile app infrastructure has been decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383026).

Comment: @Martin that did the answering for me thanks for the link!

Comment: well honestly speaking its the same answer Martin gave me but thank you @honk for mentioning it, that also answers my question!

Comment: @AshhadDevLab: That was an automated message generated after I proposed to close you question as duplicate because you said that the other Q&A answered your question.

Comment: Do know that there are several attempts to create an open source client on Stack Apps: https://stackapps.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bapp%5d%20client&searchOn=3  I'm not aware of one that currently works but if you can contribute to one of the projects you might get it off the ground.

Comment: Well tbh I was thinking of creating one myself like a handler or something, but I thought that it would fireback as a lawsuit or something. But I really think that there should be an app atleast for limited platforms. Don't you agree.

Comment: Like imagine getting involved in discussion, asking question and answering on the go without getting your laptop out.

Comment: Long story short: there was official app, it was alive for few years, and it was shut down because it did not gain enough people to use it, hence the company couldn't afford wasting money on it.

Comment: Well thats a surprising thing, I think maybe its more like people wanna make use of stuff made by others but are not appreciating their hardworking and efforts