# double confirmation for deleting?

Tags: bug, mobile-web, vote-to-delete

Recently I received the "Tenacious" badge and noticed lots of answers I have posted had received 0 votes. So I started from the oldest ones and worked my way to the recent ones, deleting the bad and/or somewhat worthless posts on my mobile.

Every time I clicked the "Delete" link, I had to confirm **twice**. Bug or feature?

(Samsung Galaxy S III on Android 4.1.2)

Comment: Cool now I know *why*! Has it been addressed?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm worried it's fallen off the radar while they're working on the [Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app), but hopefully someone will get around to fixing it sooner or later.