# Why does Stack Exchange want to access my Facebook friends list?

Tags: support, login, facebook

I just signed in to Stack Overflow via Facebook today, like I always do and got the OAuth window that asked me if I would allow Stack Exchange to access my friends list.

Why would SO want my Facebook friends list? This has never happened before.

**Add**
I logged in to a new machine for the first time today and opened Stack Overflow website on Google Chrome. I logged in via Facebook like I always do and saw the popup.

[image]

Comment: Well, that's creepy...

Comment: When you say app, do you mean the [official Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app)? Where exactly are you seeing this?

Comment: I logged in to a new machine for the first time today and opened stack overflow website on Google Chrome. I logged in via Facebook like I always do and saw the popup.

Comment: I think this is a change on Facebook's side. It happened on my own site too, even though I never set that up. Creepy indeed.

Comment: I can't vote to reopen, but this is not a duplicate of that other question. That only happens when you login for the first time. Now you have to specifically say that you allow access to your friend list when you login *again*.

Comment: Hah, I know. The bug (in the link given in the answer below) was reported today, i don't know why people duplicated this to a question asked in 2011.

Comment: I say we flag with a custom comment (not a duplicate) ;)

Comment: @ColeJohnson - go ahead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Experience this on other websites using facebook as login provider too. I guess it is related to this reported bug: [App login requesting wrong extended permissions (read_friendlists or user_friends)](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/528423520559440?browse=external_tasks_search_results_521472e6174b98716921665)

Comment: I don't trust the other questions (people marked mine as duplicate) as this never happened to me before today. Thanks for this link! :)