# Why was this question removed?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

The question is here - [Why does Stack Exchange want to access my Facebook friends list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194086/why-does-stack-exchange-want-to-access-my-facebook-friends-list)

There is a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135354/why-was-my-question-removed), but my question falls in none of the categories as explained in the top answer.

What's happening here? Anyone?

The question was genuine, and people had the similar doubt as me - they were getting an answer from there. So, I have no clue why the mod decided to delete it.

Comment: Moderators are people, and different people have varying opinions on what should stay and what should be deleted. I for one see no reason for that to be deleted. It could be useful to other people who are wondering why SE is requesting permission to their friend's list.

Comment: The closing comment was `This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Facebook bug that is not part of the Stack Exchange system.` still, that's arguably not a reason for deleting it

Comment: Deleted?? Ahem!!!

Comment: I don't even agree with the closure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was brought back. Thank you people!