# Is there ever anything helpful for me to add in the dialog box to crash reports?

Tags: discussion, android-app

Is there ever anything helpful for me to add in the dialog box to crash reports?

I did find a question with answer, [Should I send the native crash report?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196004/should-i-send-the-native-crash-report), but it is about an older testing version and I'm not clear it this is relevant to the current app or beta (I am in the beta).

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I also have this question. I'm using beta version 1.0.73, and am experiencing a number of crashes, most of which lead to an option to file a report. I'm not sure if I should give details when filing that report. Is there an answer somewhere on the site? I've searched through dupes and this is the most recent iteration I could find, although I most certainly could be wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue that's not my question here (Paul is the OP, I only edited) and anyhow no, I fear I don't have answer for this. (otherwise I would have answered this very question myself :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard I directed this to you by accident-oops! I meant to just leave it as a note on the post, as an update request.  I apologize to you and Paul! Thanks for taking the time to reply anyway, and so quickly! :)