# Does SO/SE have an iOS app?

Tags: discussion, ios

I was looking for Stack Overflow on the App Store. Is there a reason for SO/SE not to be there?

Accessing the amazing repository here through iPad would be wonderful.

Comment: Nothing official just yet but [bunch of non official apps for iPad do exist](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/ipad). :)

Comment: But: anything not-official [has very limited write access](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write).

Comment: Official iOS app is [under development](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/podcast-52-we-didnt-need-headphones).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Stack Exchange doesn't have any iOS app yet. But [we have started the Alpha version of an Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200/187824).

Comment: And that I can install on my iPad? <--- trollolol (yeah, Monday morning)

Comment: @Bart - Surely. You will require 6 to 8 weeks to install it. :)

Comment: @Bart If I delete app will it delete Stack Overflow website too????