# Posting from one site to another on the Stack Exchange Android app doesn't load the question

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app

I was browsing Stack Overflow and clicked the Q to ask a question. I changed the site to Meta. Once I posted the question it failed to load.

I guess it was because it tried to load it from Stack Overflow. I clicked retry, but no luck.

Comment: It did the same thing with this question. Additionally I couldn't load it even from clicking it on the meta site for a few minutes.

Comment: Were you looking at a question's detail when you posted the question or were you looking at the list of questions on SO?

Comment: From memory I think it says the site's list of questions

Answer (score 1):

Haven't been able to repro this from posting a question on another site while looking at a site's question list, nor from looking at a question's details and posting a question on another site.

If you can find more detailed repro steps please let me know, else for now this is a [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Comment: I [signed up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200/220538) for the alpha testing, but never got a reply. Any ideas how long it'll take?

Comment: @AmalMurali We're letting people in in waves, as we're following [Joel's guide to beta testing](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/BetaTest.html). We let in a wave of people once every few weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm waiting :)