# Allow user to move SE android app to external SD card

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Current Stack Exchange doesn't allow user to move app to external SD-Card.

Issue is that more you use app, more storage it will consume. This is really necessary for low storage devices with 256 MB, 512 MB.

Being an Android programmer, I can say it's just one line of code and by doing it, we would be able to allow user to move app to external SD-Card.

[image: app info]

Comment: I'm not in the beta yet, but I suspect that the SE app is providing a background service and maybe even a widget. This kind of app is not supposed to enable the external storage option according to Google, as it won't work if someone removes the SD card (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html).

Comment: @MadScientist That's the point but as far as I have used and tested app, there is no any background service and widget. And I think SE android app won't require to develop widget.

Comment: Pardon me (my ignorance) but... what memory are you talking about? RAM or local storage? I have used it for months, and occupied storage space is not going up. I'm at a mere 300kb. Sure, on a 256MB device even the 5MB of the app are important but.. Do they really sell devices with 256MB of storage? Just curious!

Comment: @LorenzoDematté can you see 5.63 MB in above snap?

Comment: Yes.. that's curious.. if it is 4.18 for the app, and 172kb for data.. what's the rest? How can an app grow in size? (or is "Data" here totally misleading?)

Comment: @Paresh, don't confuse RAM with storage. Moving to SD card will help with the latter, not the former. See also: [What kinds of memory does an Android device have?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17309)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of version 0.1.48 coming out later tonight the app will allow moving to external storage.

Comment: I haven't used the SE android app, nor do I know much about android development, but you push bug fixes/updates so fast!!! I think I'm gonna start using it.

Comment: @gitsitgo Its in a private alpha. Unless you already received an invitation, it will probably be some time before you get the app.

Comment: @AsheeshR Oh I see, I guess I'll wait.

Comment: @gitsitgo: [Help us test the Alpha version of our Android App](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200)

Comment: @AlEverett Unfortunately I'm being served stale gingerbread.

Comment: 0.1.48 update pls

Comment: @PareshMayani Sorry there weren't any other commits that would've made it to 0.1.48 so I decided to do a bigger update tonight rather than a tiny one on Friday, forgot to post that here.

Comment: @PareshMayani Out now! :)

Comment: @Kasra Roger that, I am in action and commenting from 0.1.48 version ;)