# Add support for OS X 10.9 Safari Push Notifications

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, safari

[Apple's page](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/) has a nice summary of the feature:

> OS X Mavericks introduces a powerful new way to keep users engaged with your website. You can now use the Apple Push Notifications Service to send notifications to your website users, right on their Mac desktop — even when Safari isn’t running. Safari Push Notifications work just like push notifications for apps. They display your website icon and notification text, which users can click to go right to your website.

Any chance Stack Exchange could add support for this, so new items in our SE inbox or new SE notifications could be pushed to Macs running Mavericks?

Comment: Doubt there are enough mac users to warrant it. + considering the dev todo is likely growing each day already.

Comment: While this sounds good it's a shame this isn't a cross platform feature

Comment: @RichardTingle Exactly my thoughts... Don't think devs will take the time to implement something *that* platform specific.

Comment: One would hope you could direct an RSS feed into such a notification tool, and SE already provides RSS feeds that may be of interest to you.

Comment: We might not get to it for a while (if ever), but it's not a bad idea.

Comment: You _could_ technically [do push messaging in Chrome](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pushMessaging.html) also.

Comment: What, as opposed to [an entire app for a specific platform](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app), @HugoDozois?

Comment: If you have Chromium / Chrome, then you can already get these notifications with [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/desktop-notifications-for/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle) even when Chrome is closed. There's also a Firefox addon, in case you don't like Chrome. More info: http://stackapps.com/questions/3780/real-time-desktop-notifications-for-stack-exchange-inbox-chrome-firefox (disclosure: I created the extensions).

Comment: @JoshCaswell If SE didn't work at all in safari then that would be a valid comparison.  It does work though, it just doesn't leverage this one additional feature.

Comment: I'm against implementing anything so heavily browser dependent. Not only here. Anywhere. Ever. I don't think that encouraging browser developers to introduce incompatibility is a good thing to do.

Comment: @James, *"Doubt there are enough mac users to warrant it"*, or: enough Mac users who care for this feature. (I am on a Mac, but I would not enable such notifications.)

Comment: I don't see what speaks against this at all. It's just a new notification channel, like E-Mail, RSS, Chrome's desktop notifications... (although the latter is a separate app and maybe this should be, too)

Comment: I voice my support for this idea.

Comment: @James: In general? No. On SO and on SE? Yes. There are a *lot* of iOS/Mac developers on SO, Ask Different draws a lot, and so on.

Comment: @Linuxios "There are a lot of iOS/Mac developers on SO" what is the total number of Mac users on Stack? Even if you actually had a figure, "a lot" is a generic and non factual term. So what's it based on? If we say "hell to it" and state *50% of every OS X user "in the world" uses Stack*, that's only about 3% of Stack users are on OS X. Is that "a lot" and should warrant a feature? Consider that many *decent* and well upvoted non-OS specific features are denied or ignored, and there is so many better things that could be added/improved/tweaked/etc that aren't OS specific ≌ Meh

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA They already do have support for Chrome's notification stuff for Chat.  For some reason they implemented that, but seem to refuse to implement it for other browsers, or for the Inbox/Notifications outside of chat.

Comment: It'd be beautiful to get instant notifications. Maybe the percentage of the Mac users on SO is not much (it's still quite high though) but it'd be a very helpful feature for those users (like me and many others) who are waiting for answers to their questions to continue their work when they are stuck. What's wrong with implementing it? Okay of course it wouldn't be on the top of the todo list of SE staff, but it's a nice addon, and I'm sure many people will find it helpful and use it.

Comment: I would love this on my Mac, mainly because I don't want to install Yet Another App that lives in my menubar just for the purpose of providing me with Inbox notifications.

Comment: Enabling this feature would definately be good for SO because it helps to decrease the delay with which people answer questions. It could even encourage nearly realtime conversations and it will increase the interactions with this platform. Think of it as an investment into marketing.

Comment: Yes, I agree. With iOS being one of the most prolific developer communities, the robust OS X developer community, and not to mention everybody else who uses Macs to develop. It seems to me that SO has plenty of Mac developers who would benefit from this.

Comment: It will be the loveliest feature!