# Notifications through the web browser

Tags: feature-request, notifications

It'd be neat if users could enable Stack Exchange notifications through [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/) and [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications).

Comment: @Glorfindel NO, it's not a duplicate. The linked one is in *browser **tabs*** while this one talks about native browser notification API, and leads to *significantly* different results.

Comment: This one is probably better: [Add support for OS X 10.9 Safari Push Notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202609/add-support-for-os-x-10-9-safari-push-notifications)

Comment: This has been proposed before, I just didn't have enough time to find the proper duplicate(s).

Comment: And here is another one: [Add desktop notifications for Chrome or Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156050/295232)

Comment: I've been using the Firefox add-on for a while now, it works perfectly.