# What's the hold-up on dealing with the duplicate question problem?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

So, given the lack of progress on [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions?lq=1) or [Huge close votes review queue on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow), I decided to stop marking questions as duplicate and start answering them with a link to the duplicate.

My first experience with that (see [ruby string split with terminal strings empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917499/ruby-string-split-with-terminal-strings-empty/19917570#19917570)) yielded significant rep benefit and, frankly, a lot more personal satisfaction than the alternative, independent of the rep.

Does anyone know what the hold-up is for dealing with the "duplicate question" problem? Is it primarily a prioritization issue at this point or is there no consensus on how best to move forward?

Comment: Well, there were at least four different strategies for incentivizing finding duplicates in the first question alone. Which one should we go with? How do we avoid bad duplicate closures (like all the other problems we've seen when adding badges to review tasks)? I had to reopen a question this morning where a Windows question was closed via the review queue as a duplicate of an iOS one. They weren't even remotely the same. I don't think it's a simple issue, so I'm not surprised we're still debating it.

Comment: FWIW, I really like the way you structured that answer, referencing a previous answer but making it specific to the asker's situation. If we could find a way to make all duplicate questions look like this, it would be pretty awesome.

Comment: @Shog9 That's one of the problems with automatically deleting the "possible duplicate of …" links.  When it doesn't take all that much to explain how the answer to the original applies to the duplicate, it seems like the most appropriate place to do it is _in_ the comment that links to the duplicate.  I'd done that a few times, and then found that those comments got auto-deleted. :(  Sure, now that I know, I create a separate comment, but without knowing the details of the comment deletion algorithm (because it's not just the auto-comments), it's always a bit risky.

Comment: @BradLarson I cling to the belief that while the paid SE staff values community input, it alone makes decisions about changes to the site and doesn't depend on us reaching consensus before moving forward. :-)

Comment: It would be really nice to get a serious and straightforward statement from the team on where they plan to go with this. It's the most depressing aspect of the system today, and *us* debating and making suggestion after suggestion doesn't mean anything at all, it's what gets implemented that counts. There hasn't been much of a dialogue with the community on the suggestions that exist.

Comment: `I decided to stop marking questions as duplicate and start answering them with a link to the duplicate.` Frankly, I think that sentence explains exactly why this hasn't been done.  Too many people won't do anything if there isn't a reward, but if there is one, they do anything (and everything - including the wrong thing) to get the reward.  (and this isn't directed at you, but more of a general observation).

Comment: @psubsee2003 :-) I think that's true for just about all human behavior. The challenge for SE is to be realistic about the intrinsic rewards associated with various activities and complement them with synthetic, extrinsic rewards. With a 80k close review queue, no way for the OP to acknowledge a duplicate and no rep gain for the person finding the duplicate, the current system is completely out of whack, imho, and it's time to experiment with something else.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I'd rather have the status quo with open un-duplicated questions (or possible dups with a couple of close votes) than a series of questions that shouldn't be duplicated that are.  While neither is ideal, the latter is actively harmful as leads future viewers to the wrong answers.  At least an unanswered duplicate forces someone to keep searching and possibly finding the duplicate in another search.

Comment: @psubsee I understand your concern, but if we approach this in a way that allows the OP to "accept" that the question is a duplicate, I think there is little risk of that. I'm too lazy to read through all the past suggestions to see if this has already been covered, but I'd be inclined to implement "marking as duplicate" through the "answer" mechanism rather than the "close" mechanism, with the main difference being that you can't get any "upvotes" on such answers, only a credit for "accept".

Comment: @Peter: believe it or not, the stuff that fails to achieve any consensus *externally* also tends to result in deadlock *internally*. Hard problems are hard.

Comment: Linking to someone else' answer and having it give you reputation feels like cheating. If you had made it community wiki, it'd have been a different story. And most new questions (with fairly popular tags) that get close votes tend to get closed fairly quickly, if it should be closed.

Comment: While I certainly appreciate the frustration that duplicated answers can cause, @Dukeling, I want to note that techniques such as the one Peter employed do offer one *killer* advantage: if an answer that links to and summarizes another question is accepted, it's *pretty unambiguous* that the question is indeed a duplicate. In a sense, it leverages the existing Q&A model to confirm duplicates - if it was possible to build this into the system (thus removing the "answer OR close" dilemma) I think it could solve a lot of problems.

Comment: @Dukeling Maybe the tags I'm dealing with are not that popular or maybe they're getting closed and I'm just not aware of it, but having questions closed promptly after I "vote to close" has been a very rare experience for me. As for linking to other SO answers feeling like cheating, do you feel the same way about linking to external documentation? To me, they feel essentially the same and I do the latter frequently. Also, I find that as with fixing a software bug, "diagnosing/analyzing the problem" is frequently 90% of the effort, so crediting an answer independent of any ref. seems ok.

Comment: Linking to someone else's answer isn't cheating. You did the digging for, and careful curation of, a duplicate that's going to help the OP, right? You understood the OP's problem and checked whether the dupe will solve it for them, didn't you? When done right, finding a dupe can be more effort than writing a quick answer. @Shog's suggestion really is the best of both worlds IMO, because it allows for tailor-made advice (which may or may not earn you rep) while *still* closing the question

Comment: @Shog9 Good point about hard problems being hard, but just to clarify, I would hope that SE staff wouldn't need to reach consensus _either_ on whether a particular approach is "best". They would only need to agree on moving forward with an "approach as experiment" with a willingness to to evaluate the results empirically.

Comment: @probablyPekka We *want* answers to be duplicated all over the place? And if copying another answer as an answer is fine, and you can get reputation from it, why would anyone VTC as a duplicate? And if no-one would be V'ing TC as duplicates, why have the functionality at all?

Comment: @Shog9 Random idea - VTC as a duplicate lets the accepted answer from the duplicate appear as an uncommentable, unvotable answer (to OP only?), with some disclaimer text at the top of it - if the user accepts it, the question instantly gets closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Dukeling Interesting language you're using (e.g. "duplicated", "copying"). The earlier question still gets referenced and the question still get "closed" with this proposal, the only real difference is relying on the "answer"and "accept" mechanisms vs. relying on the VTC mechanism. So the "purpose" remains the same (i.e. closing the question off from other answers, being marked as "duplicate", pointing to the "original" question) and that's why you have the functionality. I don't know if VTC-as-duplicate would need to remain or not.

Comment: @Dukeling Your proposal would seem to put the emphasis on a particular answer, which I don't think matches the intent of something being a duplicate _question_. With a duplicate question, I think what we are saying is that the _set_ of answers to some previous question covers the scope of the current question.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin But you did / are doing what you did / are doing (partly) because the question **doesn't** get closed a duplicate (unless I misread your question). Changing how the system works is a different story. Yeah, my proposal might need some work, if it's even viable (that's why it's just a comment).

Comment: @Dukeling Still curious why you view a reference to another SO post as being fundamentally different than a reference to some other form of documentation.

Comment: Some problems with copying another answer just occurred to me (perhaps these make a better point) - What if the answer requires modification (due to some serious flaw, deprecation, etc.), it being copied everywhere will result in all of those having to be updated. What if there are multiple / many / new answers, you're likely only copying the accept / most upvoted one, what about the rest? Having one answer on a post marked as a duplicate will greatly devalue linking to a duplicate - most people will just look at the one provided answer.

Comment: @Dukeling Not sure I get your point. Yes, I answered the question in part because VTC doesn't work reliably/quickly, but the gist of my post is that "how the system works" for duplicate questions _should_ be changed in some fashion.

Comment: @Dukeling You keep using the word "copying an answer". I have never proposed and I'm not aware of anyone who has proposed that. I'm talking about _referencing_ another _question_, with optionally some summarizing/contextual "cover statement".

Comment: @PeterAlfvin But you **did** copy the answer's content, with some customization. Note that most of my answers are things I know (and maybe looked up to double check) / figured out myself, not things I went to look for, I just link to documentation for additional reference. So no, I don't particularly approve of just copying content from external sites to give you reputation either (or think it's fundamentally different), but I don't *strongly* disapprove - [so] is a great resource and content finding its way there isn't bad (obviously content already there doesn't have this advantage).

Comment: @Dukeling Yep, I replicated the content because that's what the current SO culture requires. If the culture allowed simple answer-by-reference, I personally would do that, _particularly_ if I'm referencing authoritative documentation, as I dislike duplication in documentation as much as I dislike it in code. You're free to only answer things you already know, but that's strictly a personal choice in my opinion. I tend to primarily answer things I _don't_ already know off the top of my head because for me, SO is primarily a vehicle for learning new things (or learning them "better").

Comment: @Dukeling In this particular case, I had absolutely no idea there was a second parameter to `split` when I encountered the question. But I don't think that changes/reduces the value I provided in responding to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it primarily a prioritization issue at this point or is there no consensus on how best to move forward?

### TLDR; yes.

You're right; we haven't made much progress on improving the close-as-duplicate process. It's not because we don't think there's a problem, or that the problem's not important.

Why, then? Well, [as Shog pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207034/whats-the-hold-up-on-dealing-with-the-duplicate-question-problem#comment658280_207034)...hard problems are hard. We at SE don't typically wait until we have **unanimous** agreement on a strategy / design / plan / whatever before proceeding with it, but we **do** strive for majority consensus. There are a lot of passionate, opinionated, intelligent people who work here; sometimes, that means that people have very strongly held, polar-opposite ideas about how to solve particular problems. Because we believe in and respect each other's expertise, being unable to reach a general consensus on a project is actually a really good indicator that we're doing something wrong. (As a side note, this is a hard problem to solve even *without* trying to reach consensus.)

Beyond the fact that there's no consensus among users here, or SE staff internally, this is one issue that is very difficult to "experiment" with. We've been focusing the last few months on being more disciplined with regard to measuring the success or failure of changes, and doing incremental changes wherever possible so we get specific insight into what works and what doesn't. A lot of times, that means A/B testing old versions of a feature with new ones, which is great....when it works.

Unfortunately, duplicates are such a large, entrenched, and complex aspect of the site that A/B testing isn't really an option. We can't really have two versions live at the same time because this feature is so deeply connected to so many things. Especially with some of the more popular suggestions, like adding a rep-based incentive for finding dupes. It wouldn't be fair for us to split test a feature where one group of users was exposed to a new way to earn rep, while the other group didn't have the same opportunity.

Split testing isn't the only way to measure improvement, but this is where we get back to consensus and resource constraints. We've been [extremely busy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app) with a [whole bunch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign) of [large projects](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/08/introducing-gabe-the-smiling-community-manager/) that we *have* built consensus on; we simply haven't had the time to focus our energy on this problem. We fully agree that improvements can be made, but it hasn't been our top priority; this project is more expensive than some other projects that are a clear win. Sure, there are ways other than A/B testing that we can measure whether we've improved or worsened the duplicate process, but even if we agreed on an approach to try, we could very easily spend weeks designing and building a new system only to find out after we roll it out that it's worse than the status quo. I love experimenting with tweaks to the site, but we're not in a place where we can really justify spending that much time on something we aren't highly confident will be better than what we've got.

All that aside, I agree with you that it's an important issue. I have it in the back of my mind, and keep coming back to it. It is definitely not something we'll have time to tackle in the remainder of this calendar year because of the projects I linked above, but we're planning to come back to it in 2014.

In the meantime, keep doing what you're doing, and posting ideas here to meta if you come up with something you think would be better; even though SE staff don't actively respond to *all* posts, we do a pretty good job of keeping up with activity here.

Comment: :-) At the risk of violating another SE norm, I'd just like to say "Thank you, that was a great post. You directly and thoroughly responded to my question."

Comment: @Peter that's noise. I am flagging your comment and downvoting some contributions of yours as punishment.

Comment: Seriously though, this makes sense, and there is indeed plenty of lower hanging fruit that this hard problem... just please don't forget this

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that, of [all the suggestions out there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195355/206447), none of them will take a small amount of development time, don't require too much testing and can be accepted as not particularly high risk by most (unless you're just looking for the one-change-fix-it-all, rather than something to try which may work - think of it this way - of many small changes, one may make an unexpectedly big difference, while one large change may make no difference). I think many of us would appreciate a bit more per-suggestion feedback from [se] staff.

Comment: Having just quickly answered another question which I could have marked as dup, I've come back hear to do penance. ;-) I understand your point about difficulty of doing AB testing within a site, but while SO is unique in its volume, I think you could reasonably use other SE sites as a testing ground for some of the ideas. And I'd like to second @Dukeling's comment about per-suggestion feedback. While you're waiting for capacity and consensus, it might be helpful to produce an "official" summary of ideas you're considering and where you stand on each.