# Is there a way to join the Android beta?

Tags: support, android-app

I seem to find myself in possession of a shiny phone. As opposed to my old one, which was an abhorrent pancake sandwich of electronics, screen, and what must have been some kind of horse poop.

Is there any way for me to join the Android beta, or is that period over / the slots filled?

Comment: **Yes**.

Simply follow the instructions in [Help us test the alpha version of our Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190200).

Comment: @Krampus Are you sure the team is still checking that? Don't be so quick on the button... There's a good chance they invited the people and then decided/didn't check it again.

Comment: I am still waiting fo my invitation: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app#comment632827_190200

Comment: Yes, we are still monitoring that... @juergend - soon... soon...

Comment: Sweet. Then I take it back. Good call, @Krampus!