# Issue in site selection drop down

Tags: bug, android-app

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

1. Open the sliding menu, click on **Edit** to edit sites list.
2. Click on drop down icon to get sites list and now it will show Up icon.
3. Click on that icon (up) again, make sure you don't select any site.
4. Now click on that icon, nothing happens!

**Issue:**
If User don't select any site then it should change the state again to normal and allows user to select site(s).

[image]

Comment: Not repro'd on Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1, SE app v1.0.82 (beta). Probably has been fixed since then...

Comment: @AndrewT. It has been a year :P so yes probably has been fixed already!