# Help us test the alpha version of our iOS app

Tags: support, ios-app

We are in the early stages of development of the official Stack Exchange iOS app and we need your help with testing. To set a few expectations: there will be bugs, crashes, and missing features, all of which will be fixed in [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/146719).

We are initially targeting [iOS 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_7) on iPhones only.

To register for alpha testing [sign up here](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/18ZDfsBm35cV72Gzf88zPaMLQwrSRPwP2__RnPb-uqTs/viewform).

After you register we will send you an e-mail with instructions on how to download the app on your iPhone. **The invitations will be sent out in waves, so if you don’t get an invite immediately, be patient.**

Crash reports will be automatically reported back to us using [Crashlytics](http://crashlytics.com). Bugs or feature requests should be reported here on meta and tagged [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app). (For reporting purposes, the app version number can be displayed in the app by swiping down the side-bar, above the username and profile picture)

As always, we welcome your feedback and are committed to building the best mobile app possible for browsing the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Isn't that the same form from the [Android client release announcement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/)? If so, anyone signed up through that post should not sign up *again*, right?

Comment: @MartijnPieters no, it's a separate form, so if you wish to get invited for iOS, you *should* sign up again.

Comment: Then why do the URLs match *exactly*? I am talking about the iPhone alpha register form linked from the announcement that the Android client had been moved from beta to release.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I misread. Yes, your initial assumption is correct. I thought you meant I accidentally linked to the Android form.

Comment: I apologize in advance if this is the wrong place to ask, but is there a planned version for windows phone 8?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky so if I sent the form back when the android app was announced, when should I expect email invitation? Two weeks are not long time, but not short either. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard we're going to send out the first batch today, can't make any promises as to when you'll get yours ;)

Comment: @MeNoTalk see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215992/stack-exchange-android-app-in-beta#comment699299_215992): *at the moment we are focusing our efforts on iOS and Android.*

Comment: When will iPad users be able to sign up to help test?

Comment: @Joe Probably, but the app will run in that minimized format - where you can 2x it and everything.

Comment: @Undo I understand that that it will not run in the iPad format but what I was wondering is if iPad users should/can sign up at all right now.

Comment: What login credentials do I use? It says to sign in, not sign up, and I've never had an account like that (unless it's referring to my Stack Exchange account or my Google Account...?).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: You don't just see http://i.stack.imgur.com/sKzbF.png?

Comment: @Matt: Nope, here's what I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BII8I.png and the address bar seems to be routing the link through that authentication form. If Google is seriously trying to imply that I need to use Chrome just to access the signup form then I can forget about signing up for this.

Comment: Got the email to participate, but tapping the link gives me "cannot install applications because the certificate for mobile.stackexchange.com is not valid" -- iOS 7.1b5

Comment: I have the same issue on iOS 7.1b5. It's because [enterprise apps must be distributed on via https in 7.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1). In the meantime, open the plist in the link, copy the IPA URL and download it to your Mac. Then open Organizer in Xcode, switch to the Devices tab and drag the IPA to your phone.

Comment: So should I submit feature requests as a comment to this question? as an answer to this question? as a new question?

Comment: @IdanAdar feature requests should go in a separate question with the tags ios-app and feature-request

Comment: Any significant reason for making this iOS 7 only ?

Comment: @JohnWHSmith development effort and cost, as well as taking into consideration our actual traffic.

Comment: @bmike please open bug report for this, who said it happens to others? Maybe it's local problem with your device only, maybe you did something wrong. Don't just assume it's a bug and don't put words in the author's mouth especially in such an important post.

Comment: @joew The app is quite usable on an iPad in both 1x (small rectangle with big black frame) or 2x (smaller letter boxing - slightly awkward keyboard layout) - especially if you are reading. However, the design is clearly decluttered and optimized for phone screen size so it's probably better to use the normal web interface for iPad sized use if you're not actively testing the app for crashes on iPad.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did file a bug report on it yesterday. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220395/add-version-information-and-or-bug-report-functionality-to-ios-app and the answer from Tim Stone and Brian Nickel confirming that I'm not just "holding it wrong" :-) I reverted your rollback and expanded on the version information so that others can understand the current situation. Once the bug is fixed, let's roll back to the intended reality  wording here.

Comment: OK, sorry about that had to read again the comments. My bad!

Comment: @bmike my question was more along the line of will testing/crash info from an Ipad actually be useful to the dev team at this point.

Comment: @JoeW Got it - I'm testing it for that reason on the premise that any crash is a good one at this part in the alpha. :-) It's too soon to know if SE finds that of ongoing use or will even support the app on that line of devices. But this post is pretty clear they want iPhone only ;-)

Comment: @JoeW I think an iPad crash would be helpful, but we are only supporting  iPads currently in the same sense that Apple allows all iPhone apps to run on iPads – theoretically, all bugs are the same, although with faster/slower hardware it might be easier to find some problems.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Thanks for the information.

Comment: So if I signed up for the beta through the form on the Android app blog post about a day after it was posted, is there an ETA?

Comment: I think it would be useful to list here the known high-level features that aren't expected to work yet because they haven't been implemented. We don't need a new meta question for every feature that we already know isn't in there yet (but obviously will be added later).

Comment: @AaronBertrand While we do have a list of planned features (really parity with the Android app is the first step), the onslaught of meta posts will help us prioritize.

Comment: @Brian Ok, so you want a meta question for every single feature not yet implemented in the iOS app? For the features you already plan to implement, I'm not sure how this will be helpful, but ok...

Comment: @MeNoTalk I actually plan to write a WinPhone app when I get the time. Not too complicate, but it's planned.

Comment: I signed up for alpha testing on the day the Android app blog was posted but I still haven't received any emails regarding this. Is anything lost or am I just being impatient?

Comment: How long will I have to wait for an invite?

Comment: Could someone please tell us if those of us who didn't get an invite yet are going to get it eventually, or not? I also signed up the same day the Android app blog post was posted.

Comment: @bfavaretto yes, you will get an invite, but, as the post mentions, they are sent out in waves. So you'll have to be patient :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Arie, I'll keep waiting.

Comment: How are you distributing this app without going through the AppStore?

Comment: Applied two times, never got anything. Any estimate when the app will be released ?