# Unable to install the Stack Exchange iOS App

Tags: support, status-completed, ios-app

While trying to install version 0.1.11 of the Stack Exchange iOS app on iOS 7.1 beta 5, I get the following:

> Cannot install applications because the certificate for
>   mobile.stackexchange.com is not valid

Is the application not installable on iOS beta releases, or is something else in play?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** the download link has been moved to HTTPS, so this should no longer be an issue.

This is an issue caused by a new restriction in 7.1, as mentioned below. **We're working on moving it over to https**.

In the meantime, I believe the following comment might be useful to you:

> I have the same issue on iOS 7.1b5. It's because enterprise apps must be distributed on via https in 7.1. In the meantime, open the
>   plist in the link, copy the IPA URL and download it to your Mac. Then
>   open Organizer in Xcode, switch to the Devices tab and drag the IPA to
>   your phone. — David Caunt 4 mins ago

Source: [Help us test the alpha version of our iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220264/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-ios-app?noredirect=1#comment714145_220264)

Comment: I was just about to post that here :)

Comment: Thanks. And if one does not have Xcode? :-) Use the iPhone Config Utility  / Apple Configurator app?

Comment: @IdanAdar you should be able to do something similar with iTunes. Drag it into your iTunes library (into the apps section), and then sync. A fix for https is in the works soon, though, so you could also just wait.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky That seems like a much easier solution then installing Xcode (which I cannot install on a PC), thanks.