# Add version information and/or bug report functionality to iOS App

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

It doesn't appear to be possible to determine the version of the iOS app on v0.1.13.

Is there some hidden gesture or settings pane that displays the version of the app when I'm using the iOS app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [mentioned in the introduction post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220264/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-ios-app), if you pull down in the left gutter menu, it will show you the version information once you update to 0.1.14 or later.

Comment: It'll be somewhere better in a few days.

Comment: Hmm, as of the update a few minutes ago it seems to have disappeared

Comment: Yeah, we'll fix that too.

Comment: Changelog anyone? :)

Comment: This is where I looked for it initially and posted when it didn't work. Glad that there's a place for it once the code is fixed.

Comment: This should be fixed in tonight's build.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Excellent. What is the update mechanism for alpha testers. Does the app refuse to run when it checks in with crashlytics or do we get a push notification to return to the enrollment URL or is it a manual process? I'm familiar with Hockey.app and Testflight and manually installing builds. What are you planning for your signed updates?

Comment: @bmike you can manually update by going to the invite URL, but we also have a forced upgrade mechanism that shows an alert when you refresh the feed (on app start or manual refresh) but are on and older version of the app.

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Confirmed fix on version 0.1.14 for showing the build. The forced update notification didn't fire on the one device I updated manually and has yet to fire on the other two devices that still run 0.1.13

Comment: @bmike have you hit the feed?

Comment: @BenCollins ? I've seen one instance where the app locked itself and notified of an update. I'm on 0.1.16 across my devices at the moment so showing the feed just shows the feed so far today.

Comment: Ok.  If you notice that you are on an old version, @bmike, and hit the feed and *don't* get a version notification, please file a meta bug for it.

Comment: @BenCollins I certainly will if it happens again.

Comment: @IdanAdar [this is the changelog](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app). :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think a real changelog would indeed be a benefit, as it could encourage testing of new features and bug fixes, and also it makes each version more verifiable

Comment: @Mobiletainment I don't think so, it's still under development so full changelog will be way too technical for most people. Most users will get all they need from seeing the completed bug reported and feature requests. After being stable and public in the app store they will probably add some changelog in each version, as other apps are doing.