# iOS App Update Process?

Tags: support, ios-app

What is the process for updating the iOS app during the alpha/beta period?

My first update came as a message in the app, directing me to download a new one. But 0.1.14 I did not know of. Having heard mention of a nightly update in answers to my bug reports, I on a whim the next day deleted the app and re-downloaded, to learn that I had in fact been on an older version.

Will there be posts for new versions? Or comments/edits on a particular post? Or notifications should work going forward and it was just a bug for the 0.1.14 update?

Comment: Hmm. I'm apparently still on 0.1.9 and haven't received any in-app messages.

Comment: I got *far*
 too big a kick out of seeing that message coming from a SE developer :

Comment: Happy to be of service. ;)

Comment: Have you been avoiding the feed? The upgrade notice is locked in with loading new data into the feed, so you'll only see it on that page (after a refresh)

Comment: I did see a comment somewhere to that effect, so I refreshed the feed manually and after restarting the app. Neither showed an update, so I deleted and redownloaded.

Comment: No signs of any update on the two of my devices that still run 0.1.13. Perhaps it was there, but it's not floating to the top of the feed or otherwise distinguishable when browsing the feed. My one device running 0.1.14 did just lock itself and display the "Update Now" modal dialog.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi: I can confirm the auto-update isn't working for me. I got no auto-update when on 0.1.13, then manually upgraded to 0.1.17... which I've also had no auto-updates on... So I'm now manually updating to 0.1.25.

Comment: @Matt have you been using the feed? Refreshing the feed should be giving you a prompt.

Comment: @Kasra: Mmm.. not actively. Although since it defaults to the feed on open, won't it refresh then and show me the update notification? Regardless.. I'm be sure to manually refresh from now on to check!

Answer (score 1):

Version 0.1.14 detected a new build for me this morning. The app now refuses to do anything but send me to the update URL, so that's working as expected.

Version 0.1.13 didn't seem to show the "Update Now" dialog and need to be installed the way you installed the initial version of the app from the web page.

Comment: I received an update alert in I believe 0.1.11, so it may have only been broken on 0.1.13. But yes, it seems to be working now

Comment: I edited the post since I only had .13 to go on. Thanks @mhlester

Comment: your answer was independently confirmed on our side. nice job catching it. 0.1.13 is definitely the buggy version, but the version number doesn't show up on that one either (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220395/add-version-information-and-or-bug-report-functionality-to-ios-app)

Comment: Am I the only one not getting any updates? I think it's still on 0.1.11 for me... :(

Comment: @ian - just navigate to the URL then sent you and with one tap, you can update.