# The app is *really* slow when typing a very large question

Tags: support, ios-app

I've tried to post a crash report from my iPhone with [a big crash log](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220896/182741) but the application was really slow while typing.

The message was about 45.000 chars and I guess that the app isn't designed to handle such a big post. I pasted the content into Evernote and got no problem to add more information inside.

By the way, the app crashed while trying to post the crash log. Of course, the preview was also really slow to display.

Is there an alert if the content of a question is more than 30k chars? Because, the preview doesn't alert me about that.

Edit:
I make some test on other app with this huge crash log.

- Tweebot was horribly slow
- Mailbox was as slow as the Stackoverflow one
- Mail was really ok, like if I have nothing in my mail
- it was the same for Evernote

Comment: +1 for trying to type a 45k-character message on your phone. Wow.

Comment: I thought posts were limited to 30 000 characters.

Comment: @EdCottrell I pasted the crash log and then trying to add revelant information inside the question. I didn't type 45k char :o

Comment: @j0k Nonetheless, I am impressed!

Comment: How does the performance at 45k compare to Mail or similar apps?

Comment: I've updated my post with more info about others apps