# Will the Official Stack Exchange App become compatible with older versions of iOS?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, ios-app

Currently the Official Stack Exchange iOS app is only compatible with iOS 7.1 or later. Are there any plans to make the app more backwards compatible? I would really like to be able to view, ask and answer questions on the go without all the hassle of a browser. Or are there some particular features that are too hard to implement in older versions of iOS?

Comment: Relevant discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220400/why-does-the-ios-app-in-testing-require-ios-7 (not a dupe since it's not actually asking to support older versions, just asking why not)

Answer (score 1):

The app will have a moving target of typically the current iOS release minus one.

- When we started we just supported iOS7 because there was such a big divide between 6 and 7.
- When iOS 8 came out, we maintained support for 7 and at some point for some reason dropped anything below 7.1.
- When iOS 9 came out, we dropped support for 7.  This was important because iPad split screen depended on features from iOS 8 to work well.
- When iOS 10 comes out we will likely drop support for iOS 8.  It depends on which new features of 10 require functionality not found in 8 and how rapid the adoption of 9 and 10 are.

The main challenge is trying to do the most good with a limited amount of resources.  We have about 2% of users on iOS 7, 10% on iOS 8 and the remainder on iOS 9.  The biggest wins right now are going to be from servicing 8+.