# Swiping notification to view iOS app breaks layout

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I allowed the iOS app to deliver push notifications, so I receive incoming inbox items in the notification center. Swiping one of these notifications to bring up the app causes the UI to get all confused:

[image: confused UI]

Tapping on the inbox icon just clears the notification circle and returns the screen to the main view, I have to tap on it again to actually bring up the inbox with the item I was trying to see.

If it matters, both times I was swiping from the list of notifications on the iOS lock screen. I also was either in the feed view or had the left menu open prior to receiving the notification, as best as my memory can recall.

Comment: curious: where can we find this iOS app for testing?

Comment: See [Help us test the alpha version of our iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220264)

Comment: Got it thanks very much.

Comment: Thank you for the report @TimStone, I'm currently checking this out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was caused when opening a push notification while the left drawer (the sites menu) was already open, causing the the drawer component to break because it could not gracefully switch between the left-open and right-open states.

**I have added some logic to fix this, which should be available in the next build.**

In addition, this bug revealed some other usecases where opening a push notification might be broken, such as when the user is in the middle of drafting a question. I'll be taking care of those.