# Edit/delete comments on the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, ios-app

Can we please enable comment editing and deleting on the iOS app?

There does not seem to be any mechanism for it as of yet.

Comment: This is on the beta roadmap.

Comment: @BrianNickel To suppress more and more of these questions, can you please [address this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220264/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-ios-app#comment715278_220264)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been implemented a little while ago. Marking as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).