# iOS app needs a way to bookmark

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app, bookmarks

When stumbling across a great answer, it would be vastly nicer to be able to bookmark it than have to do a screen capture.

Otherwise: Kudos to the developers of the iOS app. It may say alpha, but it's solid, smooth, and a joy to use!

Comment: [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com), maybe?  I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @The Wobbuffet: The question is about the Stack Exchange iOS app.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn There is one for iOS?

Comment: @The Wobbuffet: Yep, it's in development - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220264

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

[image: screenshot]

(Tap the sideways `...` on the right edge of the user bar, then Share)

Also, you can favorite questions:

[image: ss2]

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks!