# Backwards compatibility with other iOS versions

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

The recently released [Stack Exchange App](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/?cb=1) looks awesome! This is something that I had been wanting for a while. Only thing is, when I went to the App Store to download it, I was told that it was only for devices running iOS 7.

One of the first comments I saw on the announcement blog post was:

> [Why does it require iOS 7? Not all of us have new phones.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/?cb=1#comment-92736)

I completely agree. More than just people running the latest version of iOS would like to use the app. According to [THIS](http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/) page here, although 85% of iPhones run iOS 7, 12% still run iOS 6. That is **1 in 8.5 iPhones** that still run iOS 6. As shown in the graph below, with the amount of iPhones that are being sold, 12% is a significant figure.

[image: Courtesy of Wikipedia]

I know I am not the only person feeling this way. Is there anyway that this can be done?

Comment: I would say 85% is a more significant figure...(I'm the proud owner of a Nokia N900 running maemo, a device not capable of running any modern app...)

Comment: @rene I agree, and that is why (I assume) they first made it for iOS 7. I only wish that they will also port it to iOS 6.

Comment: I hope you will not be disappointed if your feature request gets a `[status-declined]`....

Comment: From Stack Exchange staff member - Arie Litovsky - ["Any significant reason for making this iOS 7 only ?" "development effort and cost, as well as taking into consideration our actual traffic."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220264/#comment714937_220264)

Comment: Officially, [88% of devices are using iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/) (as of today).

Comment: @Pang How much development effort and cost would it be to make an iOS 7 app compatible with iOS 6?

Comment: @joejoe31b Lots. Many of the underlying OS elements have changed between 6 and 7 making it hard for the same UI code to behave reliably across both. There are lots of new features in 7 too; things like the login animations would be an nightmare in 6.