# What are the traffic stats for full web, mobile web per OS, Android app and iOS app?

Tags: support, statistics, traffic

[We can talk about stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242067/167646) but they're of little use when they're global stats. Can you share traffic stats of the full web site, the mobile web site per OS, the Android app and the iOS app?

These stats can help in determining whether or not a WP app would be useful, whether or not the development of Android and iOS apps was/is useful, and whether or not additional effort could be put in the mobile web site (improved UI, SPA experience, ...).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there recent stats available for browser usage, screen size, etc. for Stack Exchange site users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375747/are-there-recent-stats-available-for-browser-usage-screen-size-etc-for-stack)