# Are there recent stats available for browser usage, screen size, etc. for Stack Exchange site users?

Tags: discussion, design, statistics

I have noticed that the Stack Exchange layout is being changed from time to time and that it seems to get worse for the desktop users, a fact also mentioned in one of the top comments for [the post summary design change announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375081/311064).

My feeling is that, at least for Stack Overflow, most page views are generated on rather large screens since one typically writes some code when looking for information on SO.

I tried looking for some stats related to browsers and screen sizes, but managed only to find this [very old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15598/what-are-the-browser-and-resolution-stats-for-so-users) and these [very old stats](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/08/21/browsers-and-screen-size-on-stack-overflow/).

Are there any recent stats on this? (let's say 2021+)

It would be interesting to see how these stats break down by community as well, since it might be different.

---

Some references ([Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views#comment1224839_367609), [Updated stats on browsers used on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300640/), [Stack Overflow 2010 Analytics](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/15/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/), [Topic suggestions: What else should we ask developers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319221/topic-suggestions-what-else-should-we-ask-developers/319267#319267)) are useful, but they are not an answer to this question. If I understand correctly the answer might be that there are no publicly available stats, but that they are available to folks with  [site-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) privilege (25K+). Is this the case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views#comment1224839_367609)

Comment: These links may also be helpful: [Updated stats on browsers used on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300640/282094) (MSE), [Stack Overflow 2010 Analytics](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/15/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/) (Stack Overflow Blog), https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319221/topic-suggestions-what-else-should-we-ask-developers/319267#319267

Comment: ...How are there 3 dupe-close votes on this? The core question here is "*Are there any recent stats on [mobile v. desktop site usage]?*" As far as I can tell, the linked post doesn't actually give _any_ stats on the prevalence of mobile site usage, or screen sizes, or anything akin. Did I just miss it?

Comment: I share your frustration with the current state of the large screen views, but I think your assumption that the mobile views are somehow being purposefully preferred over desktop and somehow data will change that equation isn't correct. *Stacks is also responsive...While you don’t quite get [them] for free, it’s super easy **to build views that scale to all viewports, regardless of device or window size.*** The problem is that the goal to have one responsive view for every window size is impossible to deliver without giving up some aesthetics and functionality.