# SE Windows 10 universal App

Tags: discussion, mobile-app

Any plans for a universal Windows app for SE?

I know that SE team was not a fan of designing a Windows mobile 8 app, but now I think it is a good idea, one app will be good for many devices. It will be great help not only for Windows 10 phones but also for small 7"/8" windows 10 tablets.

Any plans?

Comment: For tablets and larger, the web page seems preferable to any native UI... I could see a notification app being a worthwhile project though.

Comment: @Shog9 not really, in smaller tablets it is quite annoying to run the mobile version of the site as it is small for the screen size, and it is also annoying to run the desktop version as it is not touch-friendly and it is large for the screen size, I have two tablets (7" and 8") and I face that. I hope you have one so you can see for yourself.

Comment: Very hard to believe. From what I see, the existing apps (android and iOS) are not getting much attention from the team, especially the android app. In my personal opinion, I really can't see them developing whole new app. Something small, that only sends notifications, as Shog mentioned, might be easier and cheaper so might happen.

Comment: @shog9 If I may I would like to differ I work only through my Lumia Phone 520

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225624/official-stack-exchange-application-for-windows-phone-os.

Comment: @ShadowWizard you do know that UWP app is different that windows phone 8.1 app?

Comment: Not sure, that's why I did not close as duplicate, just posted as comment so it appears in the Linked questions.