# Windows Phone Stack Exchange App

Tags: feature-request, mobile-app

is there a Stack Exchange app for Windows Phone? My phone will not be upgradeable to Windows 10 Mobile so it would be amazing to see an app for Stack Exchange with notification for questions, tags, communities, hats, achievements and more.

An unofficial app would also be cool.

Comment: Related: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225624/official-stack-exchange-application-for-windows-phone-os), [2](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8689/stack-exchange-app-for-windows-phone)