# What percentage of questions posted, answered, and viewed are done so from SE's apps?

Tags: discussion, android-app, ios-app

All the discussion around the S<s>E</s>O app <s>rename</s> change/rewrite has me wondering a few questions regarding the app(s) overall. I'm assuming given the push for the rebranding SE has most of this information already (which presumably drove this decision?).

Specifically:

- What percentage of questions are posted using the app?
- What percentage of answers are posted using the app?
- What percentage of views are from the app?
- What percentage of the users who download the app use it more than 30 days after downloading?
- How many users logged in more than 3 times in the past month (vs the number of downloads)?

Comment: Related: [Why was the Stack Overflow app necessary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296068/307988)

Comment: I just posted some similar metrics on [this related MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349415/472021)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi ah, that has most of the information I think I would be curious to know. Awesome!

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi That post gets close to, but does not quite address, the concerns in [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296239/what-fraction-of-new-users-come-in-through-the-mobile-site-and-the-ios-and-andro). Maybe you could give it a look if you have time?