# The Android app crashes when open notification

Tags: bug, android-app, notifications

How could I fix it? It happens both on my tablet and my phone. The app has given me this problem for a week. Before that it worked perfectly.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Samsung
- Device Model: SM-G955F

  - OS Version: 9 (G955FXXS5DSI6)

Comment: Last time I checked the apps weren't well maintained and the (mobile) web version works a lot better. Is there anything in the app that's not on the web version (genuinely curious)?

Comment: I wish it was reasonable to mark mobile App reports as a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307065/282094) - since it provides a relevant answer - but it's quite the stretch, and apparently [SO likes having the App](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296064/282094) for the additional traffic it creates (and users it converts / introduces to SE).

Comment: Honestly, I can't see how the answers to the topic you linked are relevant to my question. It only says that it is better to use the web app, rather than the android app. But, this is not a solution to my problem with SE android app. The app worked well for a while, but now it is not anymore.

Comment: @EpicKip the app has the feed. It also remembers your question sorting preference.

Comment: @TheWanderer Maybe I should try it then, I figured web had both of those

Comment: @EpicKip SE's root domain does have a feed, but that page isn't responsive.

Comment: Alchemy, the App is no longer supported, and the last paragraph of the first link I offered is this: "It doesn't make sense to advertise an inferior solution on the mobile site itself. The vast majority of users seeing that banner won't know that the app is **unsupported and inferior to the mobile site**. The reasonable expectation would be that the app provides a better experience than the mobile site, but it doesn't.". --- Development on the App is frozen (as explained when you click on the "Android-App" tag that you used), any *bug* isn't going to be fixed. Not my fault, just passing info.

Comment: Same for OnePlus 6 phone with most recent Android and App version